# is there a limit mysql auto increment

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a mysql query

```
CREATE TABLE fruits
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name varchar(30) 
)
```

Here Id is a auto increment field.
I need not know whether there is a limit for auto increment.
I need it to increment without limit.

Comment: then use BIGINT for unlimited auto increment field.

Comment: @saty: Well, for a less limited auto increment field. BIGINT will eventually also run out of numbers.

Comment: `UNSIGNED BIGINT`, 8 bytes, is limited to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 which, for practical goals, seems a pretty good approximation of "unlimited". Assuming 10 queries/second it leaves to programmers time enough to decide to invent a 32 bytes integer and to debug it.

Comment: this is fine for practical usage. wat i am looking for is a theoretically unlimited increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to know whether there's a limit, rephrase your question.

Answer now is that the max value for the chosen data type limits the number of entries. If you want unlimited entries, you should not use auto-increment but something like GUIDs.

Comment: Thank you. tis is wat i am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is limited through the data type in your case `int`.There is no unlimited data type.